# SQL query to filter from a table and then select distinct items from the filtered data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am struggling to create a SQL query so I am hoping someone is able to help me.

The idea is: I have a table called [logs].

I need to perform an initial filter on this table to narrow down my search. This will then be lets call it set A. I then need to count the unique entries in subset A.

So the issue I am having is how do I do a select on the result of a select.

Do I need to use a temp table or a view?

This query is going to be run on 100 million rows, So if there is a better performance option please speak up.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckForActiveRadioCount
    @AccountCodeStart varchar(50),
    @AccountCodeEnd varchar(50),
    @RepeaterId varchar(50),
    @DateStart varchar(50),
    @DateEND varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @_DateStart DATETIME2(2) = CAST(@DateStart as DATETIME2(2));
    DECLARE @_DateEnd DATETIME2(2) = CAST(@DateEnd as DATETIME2(2));

    DECLARE @_AcStart INT = CAST(@AccountCodeStart as INT); 
    DECLARE @_AcEnd INT = CAST(@AccountCodeEnd as INT);

    SELECT 
        messageId, time, direction, hasRouting, deviceType, unitId, accountCode, 
        clientId, data
    FROM 
        [LoggingServer].[dbo].[Logs] AS data WITH (INDEX = NCILogIdLogs) 
    WHERE
        ((deviceType = 1) OR (deviceType = 4))   
        AND (unitId LIKE @RepeaterId) 
        AND (direction = 0)
        AND (TRY_CONVERT(INT,[accountCode]) >= @_AcStart)  //ACCOUNT CODE CAN BE LETTERS, THESE SHOULD BE IGNORED
        AND (TRY_CONVERT(INT,[accountCode]) <= @_AcEnd)     //ACCOUNT CODE CAN BE LETTERS, THESE SHOULD BE IGNORED
        AND (time > @DateStart )
        AND (time < @DateEnd )  

    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT [AccoutCode]) 
    FROM 
        data AS NumberOfUniqueRadios
```

END
   GO

Issues:

How do I do the `WHERE` on the [accountCode] when a `accountCode` is a `varchar` that could be number 'ABC' (which must be ignored) or '1234' which must be included?

I want the out put to be be able to do two things:

1. Display A count of rows

and

2. Display all columns (*) of the unique rows

Comment: how do you plan to use the results? just wanted to make sure you can't simply count the rows once the data is returned to an app or something.

Comment: I would like two options. 1; to give a number of unique rows, and 2, display all coloumns of the x unique row.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you passing parameters as strings and then converting them to appropriate data types? The stored procedure should take the correct types for dates.

Why are you comparing account codes using integers, rather than strings?

Why are you specifying the use of a particular index instead of letting the engine choose the optimal execution plan?

I would think your code should look more like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckForActiveRadioCount (
    @AccountCodeStart varchar(50),
    @AccountCodeEnd varchar(50),
    @RepeaterId varchar(50),
    @DateStart DATETIME2(2),
    @DateEND DATETIME2(2)
) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCTD accountCode) as NumberOfUniqueRadios
    FROM [FSK_LoggingServer].[dbo].[Logs] l
    WHERE (deviceType IN (1, 4) AND 
          unitId LIKE @RepeaterId AND
          direction = 0 AND 
          accountCode >= @_AcStart AND accountCode <= @_AcEnd AND
          try_convert(accountCode, int) is not null and
          time > @DateStart AND time < @DateEnd;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I am still having issues with the accountCode filter, I fI remove it, it gives me results that have an accountCode within that range?

Comment: @Zapnologica . . . I don't understand your comment.